# Building Hibernate-orm from source with Gradle

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to build Hibernate-orm from source and I'm getting the following error:

```
    BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.738 secs
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:hibernate-orm marcschipperheijn$ gradle cleanEclipse eclipse
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/Shared/java/projects/hibernate/hibernate-orm/build.gradle' line: 107

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hibernate-orm'.
> Plugin with id 'maven-publish' not found.
```

My jdk is 1.7.0_51 and I'm on a Mac OS Maverick.

Any ideas? I'm new to Gradle and there doesn't seem a lot of info on this googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the [gradle wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), which is precisely used to make sure everyone on the project uses the same version of gradle. Use

```
./gradlew <tasks>
```

Comment: I did run into a subsequent issue but I think this unrelated to this issue